# Is it ok to ask if someone can tell me where a certain story might be found?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

I remember reading a story about Muhammad in which one of his followers felt that Muhammad was too kind to his wives, or too indulgent, or didn't require some formal respect from them. Something like that. But I've been through my giant pile of books and I still can't find it.

Is it ok to ask on the main site where I might find this story, if anyone knows of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevance to Islam seems pretty straightforward (it's about Muhammad, after all), and you seem to be looking for a particular known-to-exist story so it should be eminently answerable (assuming, of course, your memory isn't just messing with you).

This seems like a perfectly valid use of the [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification) tag to me.